# How can I find a box that encompasses all given boxes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have a sequence of boost geometry box types and wish to find the dimensions of a box that encompasses all of those objects.

I've noticed that boost geometry provides the [encompass](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/envelope/envelope.html) function, which seems to do what I'm asking for general geometry concepts, but I don't know how to do this for a sequence of boxes.

Basically I've just had to roll my own, but I was wondering if it was possible to simply turn a sequence of boxes into a "geometry" so that I can simply apply the `envelope` function. Here's what I've currently written:

```
// elsewhere in my code:
using Location = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using Box = boost::geometry::model::box<Location>;

// calculate the smallest box that fully encompasses all provided boxes            
template <template <typename...> class IterableContainer>                          
Box Envelope(const IterableContainer<Box>& sequence)                               
{                                                                                  
    Location minCorner(                                                            
        std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),                                        
        std::numeric_limits<double>::max());                                       

    Location maxCorner(                                                            
        std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(),                                        
        std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest());                                       

    for (auto& box : sequence)                                                     
    {                                                                              
        if (box.min_corner().x() < minCorner.x())                                  
            minCorner.x() == box.min_corner().x();                                 

        if (box.min_corner().y() < minCorner.y())                                  
            minCorner.y() == box.min_corner().y();                                 

        if (box.max_corner().x() > maxCorner.x())                                  
            maxCorner.x() == box.max_corner().x();                                 

        if (box.max_corner().y() > maxCorner.y())                                  
            maxCorner.y() == box.max_corner().y();                                 
    }                                                                              

    return Box(minCorner, maxCorner);                                              
}
```

Comment: Not just 'box' but "axis aligned bounding box".

Comment: Makes no sense. Creating geometry out of set of boxes is a slow operation.

Comment: @Yakk, in boost they're the same thing

Comment: In lieu of a custom loop, you probably want to use std::accumulate with an envelope-of-two-boxes function (you probably need such function anyway).

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure how std::accumulate will help me here, could you show me what you mean?

Comment: Sure. std::accumulate is an extremely powerful tool. In other programming languages it is usually called "fold", you may want to google for 'the fold function' or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called `std::accumulate`. You need to feed it a box-union function.

```
using Location = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using Box = boost::geometry::model::box<Location>;
double pinfi = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double ninfi = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();

Box u = std::accumulate(container.begin(), container.end(), 
                        Box(Location(pinfi,pinfi), Location(ninfi,ninfi)),
                        [](const Box& a, const Box& b) { 
                            return Box(
                                    Location(
                                     std::min(a.min_corner().x(),b.min_corner().x()),
                                     std::min(a.min_corner().y(),b.min_corner().y())),
                                    Location(
                                     std::max(a.max_corner().x(),b.max_corner().x()),
                                     std::min(a.max_corner().y(),b.max_corner().y())));

                        });
```

Update: the building blocks of this function already exist in boost::geometry. Here's complete tested code:

```
template <typename T>
Box box_encompass (T beg, T end)
{
    return std::accumulate(beg, end, boost::geometry::make_inverse<Box>(),
                [](Box a, const Box& b) -> Box {
                    boost::geometry::expand(a,b);
                    return a;
                });
}
```

Comment: `Box&`?  Why a mutable reference?  Oh, and `std::next(container.begin())` and seeding with `container.front()` gets rid of infinities, and makes the "empty container" case explicit instead of implicit, which I'd think might be wiser?

Comment: @Yakk 1. Sloppy editing, that's why. 2. That's a matter of taste. I don't see a need.

Comment: sure: but I spent some time, and I cannot find what an `empty` box should look like.  ([heck, I cannot even tell if a box is a half-open or closed region!](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_box.html))  Maybe you know more, and that is an appropriate `boost::geometry::model::box` for the empty box.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's an elegant solution but it's more of a rewrite of what I already had; I was hoping to use `boost::geometry` features, like `envelope`, which might allow me to get rid of the accumulate/loop altogether?

Comment: Yes this is a rewrite of your solution, which I consider basically correct. As I said, turning boxes to geometry just so that you could call `envelope` on it would be needlessly expensive. You can shorten the solution even more by using `make_inverse` and `expand` functions.